# nuget metapackage nested reference version management

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a metapackage that contains references to other nuget packages.

I have a problem though, one of the referenced packages is referencing another package in the metapackage but a different version of it.

So something like this

- A

  - B_v1
- B_v2

When I run my application that has the metapackage installed it resolves B_v1.

Is it possible to somehow control this, or do I always need to keep package A references up to date?

Comment: Is the consuming project `packages.config` or `PackageReference`? If `packages.config`, I think NuGet should pick the higher version. With `PackageReference` there are [a bunch of rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution), but the nearest-wins rule should cause v2 to be selected. I'd need a sample to investigate further.

Comment: @zivkan, you're right, I came back to this after the weekend, and found that the B package wasn't even directly installed in the metapackage and was referenced in multiple packages with different versions of it. I installed it directly and now the newest version gets resolved.